# Error about FMDB(Objective-c Database Library)

Tags: objective-c, fmdb

I'm developing iOS App with FMDB(Database Library of using SQLite easily).

For creating a database named "test.db", I'm writing down the following code for making the path of the database.

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = [manager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSString *documentDirs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentDirs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
```

When I tested with Xcode Simulator, I got the following error.

```
2014-07-13 21:27:44.084 ninethtest[1481:a0b] -[NSURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a5fdd0
2014-07-13 21:27:44.095 ninethtest[1481:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a5fdd0'
```

Could you tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: You assume `paths` is an array of strings but, in reality, it appears to be an array of `NSURL` objects.  Log the value of `documentDirs` and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing-up `NSString` and `NSURL` objects.  You want:

```
NSURL *documentDirs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *writableDBPath = [documentDirs URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
```

and if the FMDB API requires an `NSString` object for the database path, you can extract an `NSString` object from an `NSURL` object using:

```
NSString *writableDBPathString = [writableDBPath path];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for useful information.I can solve above error!